# Export Google Sheet Cell data with their formatting in HTML

Tags: html, google-sheets

I tried to get formatted google sheet cell data in HTML format. I tried with Google Sheet API V4 grid data. But it is not easy to convert it to HTML format. Does anyone has a solution? Please help me. ex: Suppose a cell has text **Hello** *World* I want it as
`<b>Hello</b> <i><span style="color:red">World</span></i>`

Comment: For example, when the spreadsheet including such cell is exported as HTML, that is converted to ``<span style="font-weight:bold;">Hello</span> <span style="font-style:italic;">World</span>``. Is this result what you want?

Comment: Yes. At the same time I want to identify the cell as well.

Comment: Can I ask you about the difference between the result obtained by my comment and what you want?

Comment: Sure. Difference is what is the cell we are exporting, others are same. For example A1 : `<span style="font-weight:bold;">Hello</span> <span style="font-style:italic;">World</span>`

Comment: How about modifying the difference using script?

Comment: Yes that can be done. Do you have a solution for this part please. `<span style="font-weight:bold;">Hello</span> <span style="font-style:italic;">World</span>`

Comment: I had proposed to use the script for modifying the difference. I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: What is the difference you are saying about? can you give me an example please.

Comment: I could understand to modify from ``<span style="font-weight:bold;">Hello</span> <span style="font-style:italic;">World</span>`` to ``<b>Hello</b> <i><span style="color:red">World</span></i>``. If I misunderstand your situation, I'm sorry.

Comment: Yes you have misunderstood the problem. I want to export Google Sheet Cell data in HTML format with CSS formatting. Not anything.

Comment: In order to understand correctly about what you want to do, can I ask you about the difference between the result obtained by my 1st comment and what you want?

Comment: No difference I meant somehow HTML format of google sheet cells.

Comment: In your case, the exported HTML is not what you want. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Nope. I want exported HTML.

Comment: If your issue was resolved, please add it as an answer. It will be useful for users who have the same issue.

Comment: Ok I'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: Can you provide the detail information of your issue? If you can do, please update your question by including your latest script?

Comment: Hi we used OneNote and Used OneNote Rest API. It solved our business problem.

Answer (score 0):

this is now suported via https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder

```
const value = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
.setText("foo no baz")
.setLinkUrl(0, 3, "https://bar.foo")
.setLinkUrl(7, 10, "https://abc.xyz")
.setTextStyle(7, 10, boldStyle)
.build();
```